# how to extract specific bytes from a file using unix

Tags: file, extract, byte

how do I extract 12byte chunks from a binary file at certain positions within the file.

If I wanted to extract the first 12 bytes I could do something like

```
head -c12 file.bin>output
```

If I wanted to extract 12 bytes from byte61 I could do something like

```
head -c72 file.bin|tail -c12 >output
```

Is there a simpler way if I have something like 20 12byte chunks I need to extract

thanks

Comment: If it is worth anything, you can write a shell function and feed it with the values that you need to work with the same exact commands you did.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `dd`:

```
dd bs=1 seek=60 count=12 if=file.bin of=output
```

You can write a shell loop to substitute the numbers.

You could also consider using `awk`, Perl or Python, if there's a lot of them to do or it needs to be really fast.

Comment: On Linux with coreutils 8.13 it is **skip** instead of **iseek**: `dd bs=1 skip=60 count=12 if=file.bin of=output`

Answer (score 0):

Using xxd:

```
xxd -p -seek 3d -l 12 file.bin > output
```

`3d` means `61` in hexadecimal

Using hexdump:

```
hexdump -ve '16/1 "%0.2x " "\n"' -s 3d -n 12 file.bin > output
```

Comment: `-seek` actually takes a decimal string and silently discards errors. I presume it is using `atoi()` which has a really terrible API. So `3d` actually means 3. Yes that is stupid.

Comment: It actually uses [`strtol`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/xxd/xxd.c#L572) which does provide a way of checking errors, but obviously most people don't bother.

Comment: Final note, `strtol` supports hex inputs (`0xff`) and also the insane octal mode (`0777`). So be careful!